# C while showing two times before stop

Tags: c, function, while-loop, do-while

This is the called Function:

```
    int onBattle(int level,char nomeheroi[20])
{
        const char *monsternames[4][3] = {
        {"Rat","Bat","Spider"},
        {"Goblin","Orc","Dwarf"},
        {"Dragon","Lich","Banshee"},
        {"Demon","Hydra","Giant Spider"}
        };
        //printf("monster hp:%f  , player hp:%f, player name:%s ",globalvar.monterhp, globalvar.playerhp,nomeheroi);
    char opcaobattle;
    rndMonster(level);

    while((globalvar.monterhp > 0) || (globalvar.playerhp > 0)){
    printf("Monster name:%s\n",monsternames[globalvar.monstercatego][globalvar.monsternivel]);
    printf("Monster Life:%f\n",globalvar.monterhp);
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("----------------BattleGround--------------\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Player name:%s\n", nomeheroi);
    printf("Player life:%f\n", globalvar.playerhp);
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    printf("------------------Menu------------------\n");
    printf("----------------------------------------\n");
    printf("A - Attack\n");
    printf("D - Defend\n");
    scanf("%c",&opcaobattle);
    switch(opcaobattle)
    {
        case 'a':
        danoPMonster();
        break;

        case 'd':

        break;
    }
  }

  if(globalvar.monterhp <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
  else if(globalvar.playerhp <= 0)
    {
      return 1;
    }
}
```

This is what happen:
[image: Show two times]

I dont any problem with this code to show two times before stop on Scanf, i tried Do While too and the same thing happens any help?
ps: that globalvar is a global struct and yes there is a value

Comment: You can copy text out of a console window with the mouse (possibly using Alt-Space -> Edit -> Mark, first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    scanf("%c",&opcaobattle);
```

I suggest adding a space to the conversion specifier to make sure it isn't using a left-over newline character in the stream.

```
    scanf(" %c",&opcaobattle);
```

It might be good to have a default case for the switch, too:

```
default:
    printf("Please enter one of the available commands.\n");
```

Comment: ah wow thank you so much, but i always need to space before %?

Comment: Not always, but when you use `%c` you should always think about whether you need to, since it just reads a raw byte from the file.